# No member named 'vsnprintf' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'vsprintf'?

Tags: c++, ios, c, macos, boost

I am trying to compile boost under iOS, but every time I try to launch my project errors occurs like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:79:28: No member named 'vsnprintf' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'vsprintf'?
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:79:60: Too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
```

I think that the main reason is compiler, I try to change some settings and play with compiler but every time new errors occurs, so here are my current settings for compiler,

1. C Language Dialector - C99[-std=c99]
2. C++ Language Dialector - C++98[-std=C++98]
3. C++ Standard library - libstdc++

> Boost version is 1.44.0, 
>   XCode version is 4.5

Anybody knows how I must configurate my project to compile boost under iOS ?

Comment: Trying including `<stdio.h>` instead of `<cstdio>` and call `vsnprintf` instead of `std::vsnprintf`. A bit of a kludge, but if your compiler isn't fully C++11 compliant, you don't have much choice.

Comment: I can't do that changes as error is in c++locale.h which is not my file it is system file :((@DavidHammen

Comment: Did you search the 'net for this problem? It's all over the place, and so is the solution. Apparently you enabled the "recursive" checkbox in the tool's "Header Search Paths" menu. Uncheck it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this reference page for [`vsnprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) it was introduced in C++11, so instead of `-std=C++98` try `-std=C++0x` (however, the compiler may not support all features introduced in C++11).

Comment: It's `-std=c++0x`, not `-std=C++11`.

Comment: @DavidHammen but there is no -std=c++0x in the properties there are only following values:

C++98[-std=c++98]
GNU++98[-std=gnu++98]
C++11[-std=c++11]
GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]

Comment: @DavidHammen so how I can set C++ Language Dialect property to -std=c++0x ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers Have you found the solution?